# It is true that $T\otimes_S L\simeq L$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $\phi : (R, m, K)\rightarrow (S, n, L)$ be a homomorphism of noetherian local rings and $T:= S/mS$. It is true that  $T\otimes_S L\simeq L$?

I noticed that

$T\otimes_S L\simeq (R/m\otimes_R S)\otimes_S L\simeq R/m \otimes_R(S\otimes_S L)\simeq R/m\otimes_RL\simeq L/mL\simeq \frac {S/n} {(\phi(m), n)/n}\simeq L $  because  the submodule generated by $\phi(m)\subseteq  n$.

Comment: So you assume the homomorphism to be *local* ? Then it is true.

Comment: @MooS  The submodule generated by  $\phi(m)$ isn't included in $n$?

Comment: In general this is false, for instance consider the inclusion of any local domain into its fraction field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, your computatations are ok, we have indeed $$T \otimes_S L = S/(n+mS).$$

This is equal to $L$ if $mS \subset n$ (i.e. if the homomorphism is local) and it is zero in the other case, i.e. if $mS=S$.

Answer (score 1):

As @Moos points out you need $\phi$ to be a local homomorphism
($n=\phi^{-1}(m)$). For a counter-example for non-local $\phi$
let $R=\Bbb Z_{(2)}$, the ring of rationals with odd denominators
(so $m=2R$) and $S$ to be the localisation of $\Bbb Q[X]$
at $X$, so the ring of rational functions $f(X)/g(X)$ over $\Bbb Q$
with $g(0)\ne0$ (then $n=XS$). Take $\phi$ to be the inclusion map.